# Using my own logic for list.sort(), attempted to emulate other sources, why am I getting errors for seemingly proper formatting?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I've tried a few other approaches such as making a struct and making a separate class for the comparer as I found examples of these online but with no success. So I came back to this method since it is seemingly the simplest but even upon emulating other questions here on stackoverflow I'm unable to get it to run.

I have a specific instance where I need to compare nodes not by their default values but by another data member they all store (which happens to be an int). So I'm attempting to use my own compare with std::list.sort() but it's giving me these 2 compiler errors:

```
error C3867: 'ThreadedBST<std::string>::compareAscendFreq': function call missing argument list; use '&ThreadedBST<std::string>::compareAscendFreq' to create a pointer to member

 error C2660: 'std::list<node<T>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::sort' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

Here is my compare method:

```
template <typename T>
bool ThreadedBST<T>::compareAscendFreq(const node<T>& first, const node<T>& second) {
    return (first.getFrequency() < second.getFrequency());
}
```

and this is how I'm calling it:

```
storage.sort(compareAscendFreq);
```

Which is exactly how every reference I've found tells how to do it. To say the least I'm very confused as to why it's not working properly.

EDIT: Here's my header declaration if it's necessary

```
bool compareAscendFreq(const node<T>&, const node<T>&);
```

EDIT2: First error was resolved by making it a free standing function. The 2nd error still sticks:

```
error C2660: 'std::list<node<T>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::sort' : function does not take 1 arguments
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=node<std::string>
1>          ]
```

Comment: Is your compare function a non-member or a static member? It needs to be one of the two. It cannot be a non-static member function.

Comment: You can't pass a member function as a comparator. It needs to be a free function.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but don't sort compare functions also need to signal when the two objects are equal, not just < or >?

Comment: @asawyer: Nope -- `list`'s sort expects `operator<` behavior.

Comment: @Milan: Also note that you'll probably be better served by `vector` over `list` in most cases.

Comment: @BillyONeal a vector doesn't have the sort capabilities that I need though but yes I would agree in general

Comment: @Milan: Yes, it does. Vector is sorted by the nonmember `std::sort` in `<algorithm>`. Your call would look something like this, where `v` is your vector: `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), &compareAscendFreq<T>);`. List only has a member sort because it only provides bidirectional iterators, and `std::sort` requires random access iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ThreadedBST<std::string>::compareAscendFreq
```

this implies that compareAscendFreq is a member function -- that is, that it requires a `this` pointer. You need to supply 3 arguments to call it:

```
a.compareAscendFreq(b, c);
```

while `sort` needs a two argument comparison function.

There is no reason to make `compareAscendFreq` a member of a class; make it a free standing function.

Comment: That took care of the first error about "missing argument list."

The second error still lingers "error C2660: 'std::list<node<T>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::sort' : function does not take 1 arguments"

Comment: @Milan: Something caused type deduction to fail, which snips out the overload taking a comparison function from the candidate set. For instance, you'll need to pass `&compareAscendFreq<T>`, where T is the type of node in the list. Argument deduction is done only for the comparison function type, not for arguments into that comparison function.

Comment: One can either make the comparator a non-member and inline it or make it static member function. Either option should work.